# Download png file after XMLHttpRequest POST

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have a website that sends data in the form of a standard XMLHttpRequest to a java servlet as follows

```
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open("POST", "/GraphingServlet/FC/ExportPng", false);
xmlHttp.send("some_data");
```

My java servlet recieves this request, creates a png in binary encoding and sends this png back to the website doing the something along the lines of the following

```
response.setContentType("image/png");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"picture.png\"");
response.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
out.write(byte_array_of_binary_encoded_png);
out.flush();
```

Through firebug I see that my webpage recieves a whole lot of information but I get no download popup. How do I get the website to prompt the user to save this png as "picture.png" upon recieving the png encoded within the http response?

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not download files via AJAX. However, you can do the following:

**HTML**:

```
<button type="button" onclick="download()">Donwload</button>

<form name="downloadForm" action="/GraphingServlet/FC/ExportPng"
  method="post" target="secretFrame" style="display: none;">
  <input type="hidden" id="param1" name="param1"> 
  <input type="hidden" id="param2" name="param2">
</form>

<iframe name="secretFrame" style="display: none;"></iframe>
```

**JS**:

```
function download() {
  document.getElementById("param1").value = "some_data";
  document.getElementById("param2").value = "some_data";
  document.forms["downloadForm"].submit();
}
```

Comment: This worked great! Thanks. Could you just clarify what the purpose of the hidden iFrame is?

Comment: The purpose is not to change the content of the current page or create a new browser tab.